# How to Create OLAP cubes programmatically using Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, etl, database-administration, cubes, cube-script

I am new to SQL Server Data Tools. After browsing the internet to learn the BI suite I found out that SSIS SSAS SSRS has more than just drag and drop. People are actually creating cubes and databases programmatically. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any resources on internet to learn how to code like this. Kindly guide me or share some links to learn to create cubes and databases programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Using [BIML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Intelligence_Markup_Language) you can create SSIS packages programmatically. Combining BIML and [TMSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tmsl/tabular-model-scripting-language-tmsl-reference) allows you to script cube creation and processing. If you're set on creating multidimensional cubes and not tabular cubes then look at [MDX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/mdx/the-basic-mdx-script-mdx?view=asallproducts-allversions).

Start by downloading [BIML express](https://www.varigence.com/BimlExpress) for [Visual Studio Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15).
Then start to look at the connector for [Analysis Server](https://varigence.com/Documentation/Samples/Biml/Analysis+Services) and the [AnalysisServicesExecuteDdl](https://docs.varigence.com/biml/language-reference/Varigence.Languages.Biml.Task.AstAnalysisServicesExecuteDdlTaskNode) element which allows you to write TMSL inside the component. Now, using TMSL you can [create a cube](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tmsl/create-command-tmsl). 
Why not just use BIML for everything and skip TMSL? Using TMSL instead of the available BIML elements for handling cubes removes the need to have BIML Studio ($$$) installed.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but thanks alot for help !

Comment: can you please explain that as my new role of BI Consultant 3 months in my career will it be worth my while learn BIML and TMSL or should i work with without it? As of now there is no resource in my comany who knows BIML and TTMSL, bu i want to advance my skills and see my self as full stack BI developer.

Comment: I think there are simpler tools depending on the solution you want to build. Starting off with writing BIML and TMSL might be a lot. But if you want to be able to control the ETL in detail this is the way to go. For TMSL I usually use a combination of writing the code myself and using [Tabular Editor](https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/tabular-editor/). For SSIS I always use BIML. But if the client allows cloud solutions check out the different etl tools for Azure (Data Factory) and Google.